# Versions `__v` not appearing in documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

No `__v` is appering with in my schemas. I've read that by default it should appear with all the documents. I even tried to force it by setting `options = {versionKey: true}`.

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const options = {
    versionKey: true
};

const schema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    ports_server: Array
}, options);

const Host = mongoose.model('Host', schema);

module.exports = Host;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The `__v` was not appearing because I was **upserting** my documents. Instead of `Host.update(..)` and `Host.create(..)` I had to `new Host(..).save()`.

Proper way to upsert 1 document only is

```
    Host.findByIdAndUpdate(
        host._id,
        host,
        {upsert: true},
        callback
    );
```